# Can I use Quartz Scheduler to launch my application?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a Java **desktop application** that I'd like to *completely exit*, and schedule it to *launch at a later date.*

Is there any way of using Quartz Scheduler for this?

As far as I understand, Quartz requires a Java runtime to be **running** for it to activate.

I'd like the following functionality, and would not mind using another Java library to achieve this:

- Get/Set schedules for execution of a Java application.
- Be able to launch the application without having a Java runtime.
- Maintain a cross-platform codebase.

Comment: We'll, your not going to be able to launch a Java application without some form of Java runtime, so not sure what you mean there. But in answer to your first question, you can run Quartz as a completely standalone process, and have your application schedule itself with it, on exit.

Comment: "Be able to launch the application without having a Java runtime." - it's hard to run java app without java. Could you please explain this requirements?

Comment: @Perception Can I not run it from the command-line? If Java is installed correctly on the client machine, the "java" command should be available from /usr/bin

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, you need to wedge it outside the code.